# How to average n adjacent columns together in python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is a histogram with 2000 bins, with a column for each bin. I need to reduce it down to a quarter of the size - 500 bins.

Let's say we have the original dataframe:

A B C D E F G H

1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

I want to reduce it to a new quarter width dataframe:

A B

1 2

where in the new dataframe, A is the average of A+B+C+D/4 in the original dataframe.

Feels like it should be easy, but can't work out how to do it! Cheers :)

Comment: The logic is unclear, do you always have 8 columns? or a multiple of 4? What if the column names were shuffled? Why is there B in the output?

Comment: Hi there, let's say I just have a multiple of 4. I have 2000 cols and want to average down to 500, I just used 8 hear as its a low multiple of 4 ;)
The A B C etc are just column indicators, A is col 0, B is col 1 etc

Comment: Then the logic provided in my solution works (except the second part with renaming, you would need to give more details for that part as there are not 500 different letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to group the first 4 and last 4 columns (or any number of columns 4 by 4):

```
out = df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1])//4, axis=1).mean()
```

ouput:

```
     0    1
0  1.0  2.0
```

If you further want to relabel the columns A/B:

```
out = (df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1])//4, axis=1).mean()
         .set_axis(['A', 'B'], axis=1)
       )
```

output:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  2.0
```